# td value to mysql

Tags: php

im new in php! i currently display data from MySQL every time i search for name or idnumber and display all in to the html table but when i click the button on the table row i get the last value of the data.

here is the code i made:

```
$searchdata=mysql_query("select * from tblstudent where Last_name   
     ='".$search."'")or die("Error Query");
            if(isset($_POST['Search'])){
            if(empty($search)){
                $error_2="Search Box is empty";
                }
                elseif(strlen($search)<1){
                $error_2="ERROR SEARCH";
                }
                else{
                //display data to the table
                echo "<div id='res'><form id='form1' method='POST' action=".basename(__FILE__).">
                    Reservation Fees:<input id='descriptive' name='reserv' type='text'  />  ";
                 echo "<table id='example' border='1'>
                                <tr>

                                    <th>ID NUMBER</th>
                                    <th>LAST NAME</th>
                                    <th>FIRST NAME</th>
                                    <th>MIDDLE NAME</th>
                                    <th>COURSE</th>
                                    <th>GENDER</th>

                                </tr>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($searchdata)){
                $studentid=$row['student_id'];
                $coursee=$row['Course'];
                $lnamee=$row['Last_name'];
                $fnamee=$row['First_name'];
                $mnamee=$row['M_name'];
                $gnder=$row['Gender'];

                echo "

                    <tr>
                        <td>".$studentid." <input type='hidden' name='dummyID' value='$studentid'></td>
                        <td>".$lnamee." <input type='hidden' name='dummylname' value='$lnamee'></td>
                        <td>".$fnamee."<input type='hidden' name='dummyfname' value='$fnamee'></td>
                        <td>".$mnamee."<input type='hidden' name='dummymname' value='$mnamee'></td>
                        <td>".$coursee."<input type='hidden' name='dummycourse' value='$coursee'></td>
                        <td>".$gnder."<input type='hidden' name='dummygnder' value='$gnder'></td>
                        <td><input id='send' name='add' type='submit' value='Reserve' /></td>
                        </tr>";

    }
    echo "</table>
     </form></div>";
}}}
```

Comment: You know it isn't safe against MySQL injections? And you should have a look LIKE too. To make better search queries :)
Further, I don't really understand what your question is.

Comment: have u run that query in ur phpmyadmin?? i think ur logic is correct.

Comment: @Sietse sorry i dont know that isnt safe in mysql and im sorry for the question i made! what i trying to say is every time i search for the last name of the student like two relatives lastname that appear in the table every time i click one of the td it display the last value of the the
<tr><td>value1</td></tr> <tr><td>value2</td></tr> if i click the value 1 it display value2 hope you understand! and thank you for reply

Comment: @diecho yes sir i tested it and it works fine but when it display in a multiple table row and every time i click one of the table row it display the last value that been display in the table

Answer (score 1):

you have a form with multiple elements named dummyID, dummylname, etc.  So the value that gets submitted is just the last one you output.

Add in an index {$i} to determine which row is being submitted.

```
$i = 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($searchdata)){
    $studentid=$row['student_id'];
    $coursee=$row['Course'];
    $lnamee=$row['Last_name'];
    $fnamee=$row['First_name'];
    $mnamee=$row['M_name'];
    $gnder=$row['Gender'];

    echo "

        <tr>
            <td>".$studentid." <input type='hidden' name='dummyID[$i]' value='$studentid'></td>
            <td>".$lnamee." <input type='hidden' name='dummylname[$i]' value='$lnamee'></td>
            <td>".$fnamee."<input type='hidden' name='dummyfname[$i]' value='$fnamee'></td>
            <td>".$mnamee."<input type='hidden' name='dummymname[$i]' value='$mnamee'></td>
            <td>".$coursee."<input type='hidden' name='dummycourse[$i]' value='$coursee'></td>
            <td>".$gnder."<input type='hidden' name='dummygnder[$i]' value='$gnder'></td>
            <td><input id='send' name='add[$i]' type='submit' value='Reserve' /></td>
        </tr>";
    $i++

}
```

Then process the data like:

```
if(!empty($_POST['add'])) {
    $i = current(array_keys($_POST['add']));
    $studentid=$_POST['dummyID'][$i]
    $coursee=$_POST['dummycourse'][$i];
    $lnamee=$_POST['dummylname'][$i];
    $fnamee=$_POST['dummyfname'][$i];
    $mnamee=$_POST['dummymname'][$i];
    $gnder=$_POST['dummygnder'][$i];
}
```